# Unity free painting

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, draw, paint

Does Unity have any analogue of HTML or Delphi Canvas? I want to draw points, lines and other primitives.

Comment: example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRJcIoYI3ZE

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to draw it with [GL](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.html). It's a Low-level graphics library. You'll have to do some coding to use it.

There's also the asset store to do it. For exemple I use [Shapes](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/shapes-173167) from Freya Hölmer. (It's a paid asset and you wont use any tag code like html to do it, you can manage it by using asset's scripts).